# Detecting similar paragraphs in two documents

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to find similar paragraphs in 2 documents. Each document has many paragraphs of multiple lines of text. The text in paragraphs has some changes. The words can be inserted or deleted or miss-spelled. For example

Doc1.Para

This is one line of text

Doc2.Para

This is one lin text

You can see here that some words are missing('of') and some are spelled differently. Hence the paras are **not exactly same but similar**. And the similarity is not based on the semantics or essence. Its just based on the words.

The paragraphs are not in same order. For example

Doc 1
Para 1
Para 2
Para 3
Para 4

Doc 2
Para 3
Para 4
Para 1.1
Para 2
Para 1.2

Here you can see order is not same. Also paras can be **splited** like Doc1.Para1 is splited into 2 paras Doc2.Para1.1 + Doc2.Para1.2.

I have to detect which para in Doc1 is similar to which para in Doc2. Looking for some open source tool or some algorithm.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.Can you suggest me solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've previously had success with using word embeddings to capture paragraph similarity. Word embeddings, such as those produced by Google's [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/), model words in a high-dimensional vector space. As such, they make it possible to compute the semantic similarity between two words, for example as a cosine between their individual vectors. You can download these embeddings directly from the word2vec site, or from related project sites such as [Polyglot](https://sites.google.com/site/rmyeid/projects/polyglot).

In order to model similarity between paragraphs, one simple solution is to compute paragraph embeddings by taking a weighted sum of the embeddings of all the words in that paragraph. Because some words are more informative than others, you can weight the word embeddings by the [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) of the word, for example. You can then compute the similarity between two paragraphs as the cosine between their embeddings.

Comment: I am not looking for semantic similarity between two word....i just want to get exact similarity...the tools you have mentioned do they apply for this type of problem also?...anyways i will read abt it

Comment: Aha. Well, in that case you should probably go with the Levenshtein Distance, as suggested in the other answer by felipeclopes.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to compare two paragraphs only by comparing the text and word similarity is using an algorithm called [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It compare distance between two texts, and you can use the threshold that better suits your need.

For example, all text above 90% similarity should be considered the same.

Comment: Thanks. I am considering that....but I am worried abt time complexity. Lets say i have m & n paras in each doc respectively. I have to apply Levenshtein Distance algo for each combination i.e. m X n times(actually even more because paras can be splited so i have to try combination of 1 or more para against 1 or more). The complexity of single Levenshtein Distance step itself is equal to product of length of 2 strings. Imagine there are 100 paras each of 100 words

Comment: There is also the possibility of using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing that do well with texts. It is more to cluster them together into "buckets" of similarity, it should do great in terms of performance, maybe you can hack into comparing the paragraphs when they match the buckets only ;)

Answer (score 0):

There has been many sharedTasks in NLP community on textual similarity/entailment (STS 2015, 2014, 2013, RTE 2010, ...) etc. This is the latest competition:

http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2015/task2/index.php?id=semantic-textual-similarity-for-english

Some of them release the submitted systems or the baseline to use which I assume you can use for your task as well. Have a look at this:

http://ixa2.si.ehu.es/stswiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

1. You can also use [Apache Spark 2.0](http://spark.apache.org/) which has a rich in ML and
   has many robust algorithms built in terms of Document similarity.
2. Sample programs/Example Programs can be downloaded from
   this [site](https://github.com/apache/spark).

Answer (score 0):

You write you're worried about time complexity – one common method to avoid slow comparisons over the product of all paragraphs is *[shingling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling)*.

In short, you

1. create a set of sketches/fingerprints of all paragraphs (run each paragraph through a set of hash functions),
2. make a map from sketches to the paragraphs that have that sketch.
3. reverse that into a map from paragraph-pairs to number of sketches in common,
4. filter at a certain threshold, and
5. go from pairs to groups by clustering with [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

See
http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/near-duplicates-and-shingling-1.html the details. I have a [simple OCaml implementation](https://github.com/unhammer/wshiml) that may be helpful, but there are probably libraries in lots of other languages if you search for document shingling.

Comment: interesting...i moved away from that project but thanks its good to know

Answer (score 0):

Your question relates to plagiarism detection in Natural Language Processing. 
A choice could be to use a fingerprinting algorithm. Since the order of paragraphs is not important, I suggest the following paper:

[Winnowing: Local Algorithms for Document Fingerprinting](https://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/publications/papers/sigmod03.pdf)